# Less include path

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, less

I'm isolating bootstrap classes into a top class to avoid conflicts with my own page's CSS, as pointed by Chris Youderian in [this post](https://formden.com/blog/isolate-bootstrap). I use the following `bootstrap-custom.less` file:

```
.bootstrap-custom {
  @import (less) '../libs/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css';
}
```

The problem is that when I use glyphicons, it looks for fonts relative to the path of my `bootstrap-custom.less`, and not the path where `bootstrap.css` is.

I don't want to put `bootstrap-custom.less` inside bootstrap's folder because It's a dependency managed by `bower` and it doesn't seem right.

Is there a way to solve it without modifying bootstrap's code? Again, I don't want to do it because it's a dependency managed by the package manager.

Comment: [`--relative-urls`](http://lesscss.org/usage/#command-line-usage-relative-urls).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved my problem.

I only had to redeclare the `font-family` inside my `bootstrap-custom.less` relative to itself, as follows:

```
.bootstrap-custom {
    @import (less) '../libs/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css';

    @font-face {
      font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';

      src: url('../libs/bootstrap/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');
      src: url('../libs/bootstrap/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
           url('../libs/bootstrap/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2') format('woff2'),
           url('../libs/bootstrap/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff') format('woff'),
           url('../libs/bootstrap/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf') format('truetype'),
           url('../libs/bootstrap/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons_halflingsregular') format('svg');
    }
}
```

I will use this for now but maybe someone comes up with a better solution.